# How to write wildcard search query in couchdb where name like 'a%'

Tags: json, couchdb

How can I write wildcard search in couchdb? I want to write query same as 'LIKE %' in sql.please help me for this.

```
 {
"name":"arun",
"surname":"mr"
}

 {
"name":"balu",
"surname":"tp"
}
```

I need to list all names that start with 'a'.

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In couchdb you can query over [string ranges](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#String_Ranges).

First you need to have a view that emits all the names as keys

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.name)
  emit(doc.name,null);
}
```

Then you can query it with

`http://localhost:5984/your-db-name/_design/your-ddoc-name/_view/your-view-name?startkey="a"&endkey="a\ufff0"` which will give you all the names starting with `a`.

'\uff0' is just a high value unicode character, not a specific character that will perform magic tricks in couchdb.