# How can i write query with OR case in couchdb

Tags: java, json, couchdb

I want to write a query in couchdb same as below sql.

select * from tbl_name where f_name like 'a%' or l_name like 'a%';

for the given document:

{

"f_name":"abc",

"l_name":"def"

}

I need result by using view and its should not use any list.Alternatively i want to change the field name in where case.

eg:

select * from tbl_name where f_name like 'a%' ;

select * from tbl_name where l_name like 'a';

The field name present in where condition should be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For wildcard query, have a look here: [How to write wildcard search query in couchdb where name like 'a%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909317/how-to-write-wildcard-search-query-in-couchdb-where-name-like-a/24911637#24911637)

In your view, just output both `f_name` and `l_name` as keys, **two** emits that is.